# background-color заливает цветом не всю часть страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: мне нужно изменить цвет фона определённой части страницы, но при использовании background-color цвет меняется не на всю страницу, остаётся немного места по бокам.

[image: На ненужное место указывает стрелка]

Ниже код.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Проверка</title>
</head>

<body style="color: white; background-color: #101010; font-family: Arial;">
  <header style="background-color: #1e1e1e; size: 20;">
    <p align="center">Такой-то сайт</p>
  </header>
  <main>Что-то там</main>
  <footer style="background-color: #1e1e1e;">Контактные данные:<br><a href="blahblah@blah.blah">blahblah@blah.blah</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `body {margin: 0;}`; И стили лучше писать в [отдельном файле](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), а не в атрибуте `style`.

Comment: @De.Minov спасибо! И да, я просто хотел показать css в одном коде с главным файлом - вдруг это важно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большинство элементов HTML имеют стили по умолчанию, для `body` это `{ display : block; margin : 8px; }`.

Поэтому нужно добавить правило `margin: 0px;` к стилю `body`:

```html
<body style="margin: 0px; color: white; background-color: #101010; font-family: Arial;">
```

Подробнее дефолтные стили можно посмотреть, например, тут: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp